# Why solving Knapsack problem is not considered as linear programming?

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, knapsack-problem

Why isn't the knapsack problem included under the category of *linear programming algorithms* in spite of the fact that the Knapsack problem statement seems similar to the problems in *linear programming*?

Comment: @yes123 In linear programming, it's the constraints that are linear, not the time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Knapsack can be written as an *integer linear programming* program. Unlike normal linear programming, this problem requires that variables in the solution are integers. Linear programming is known to be solvable in polynomial time, while integer linear programming is NP-complete.

Exercise for the reader: show that 3SAT can be reduced to integer linear programming.

Trivia: there are approximation algorithms for problems such as MAX-3SAT (a variant of 3SAT where we want to maximize the number of satisfied clauses). First you write MAX-3SAT as an integer linear program. Then, you *relax* it to linear program, by removing the integer restriction. Then, you solve the linear program in polynomial time. Finally, given real x<sub>i</sub> ∈ [0,1], you round them to integers, or generate random integer solution y<sub>i</sub> where probability of y<sub>i</sub> = 1 is x<sub>i</sub>.

Comment: It's worth to note that in general it's often relatively easy to reduce given NP problem to ILP.