# Computing the optimal combination

Tags: java, android, algorithm, dynamic-programming, linear-programming

I am designing an application wherein I need to choose from a group of fertilizers, the best possible combination, i.e the minimum amount of fertilizers which can supply the given nutrients.

For example, suppose i need to supply 23g N(Nitrogen) and 23g P(Phosphorus) and I have the following two sets of fertilizers :

**Set 1 :**
Fertilizer        N          P           K         (in g / 100 Kg)
A             23         23          0
B              18  46   0
C             46   0             0

**Set 2 :** 
Fertilizer        N          P           K         (in g / 100 Kg)
D             23         23          0
E              18  46   0
F             16   0             0

In step 1 : 
We could choose 50 Kg of Fertilizer B obtaining 23g P and choose ~30 Kg of Fertilizer C to obtain the required N. Which totals 80 Kg, instead of choosing a 100Kg of Fertilizer A.
In step 2 : 
We would be better off choosing 100 Kg of Fertilizer D than choosing Fertilizer E and Fertilizer F.

Now , I am trying to come up an algorithm that computes the optimal combination. I believe a Greedy Approach won't work. So I tried Dynamic Programming on a 3D Matrix for all possible integral values for N, P, K but that leads to loss of precision. And i only have limited resources.
Can anyone suggest any other method for the same ? 
I feel that maybe this could be modelled as a graph problem but I don't know how.


Here is the code for the dynamic programming i wrote :

```
void evaluateChoices() {
        dp = new int[MAX + 1][MAX + 1][MAX + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
                for(int k = 0; k < MAX; k++) {
                        if(i == 0 && j == 0 && k == 0) {
                            dp[0][0][0] = 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            considerCurrent(i, j, k);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }


void considerCurrent(int i, int j, int k) {
    int minyet = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int choice = 0; choice < numFertilizers; choice++) {
        fertilizer fertilizerOption = fertilizerChoices[choice];
        int amount;
        if(fertilizerOption.N >= fertilizerOption.K && fertilizerOption.N >= fertilizerOption.P) {
            amount = (100 / fertilizerOption.N) * i;
            if(amount == 0) {                               // required amount is amount of N i.e i
                continue;
            }
            if(((j - (fertilizerOption.P / 100)) * amount) >= 0 && ((k - (fertilizerOption.K / 100)) * amount) >= 0) {
                int jIndex = (j - ((fertilizerOption.P / 100) * amount));
                int kIndex = (k - ((fertilizerOption.K / 100) * amount));
                if(dp[0][jIndex][kIndex] + amount < minyet) {
                    dp[i][j][k] = dp[0][jIndex][kIndex] + amount;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(fertilizerOption.P >= fertilizerOption.K && fertilizerOption.P >= fertilizerOption.N) {
            amount = (100 / fertilizerOption.P) * j;
            if(amount == 0) {                               // required amount is amount of P i.e j
                continue;
            }
            if(((i - (fertilizerOption.N / 100)) * amount) >= 0 && ((k - (fertilizerOption.K / 100)) * amount) >= 0) {
                int iIndex = (i - ((fertilizerOption.N / 100) * amount));
                int kIndex = (k - ((fertilizerOption.K / 100) * amount));
                if(dp[iIndex][0][kIndex] + amount < minyet) {
                    dp[i][j][k] = dp[iIndex][0][kIndex] + amount;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            amount = (100 / fertilizerOption.K) * k;
            if(amount == 0) {                               // required amount is amount of K i.e k
                continue;
            }
            if((i - ((fertilizerOption.N / 100) * amount)) >= 0 && (j - ((fertilizerOption.P / 100) * amount)) >= 0) {
                int iIndex = ((i - (fertilizerOption.N / 100) * amount));
                int jIndex = ((j - (fertilizerOption.P / 100)  * amount));
                if(dp[iIndex][jIndex][0] + amount < minyet) {
                    dp[i][j][k] = dp[iIndex][jIndex][0] + amount;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here i, j, k is the N, P, K values.
The problem I am facing is that when i calculate indices such as :

```
int jIndex = (j - ((fertilizerOption.P / 100) * amount));
```

I am losing precision and I cant really help it as I am mapping it to array indices.

Comment: This is pure dynamic programming.

Comment: Wait, I'll put up the code as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is called a Linear Program. You are doing Linear Optimization.
You can use the [Simplex Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) to solve tasks like this.

Comment: Could you please illustrate with the help of an example what all equations you could use for this problem?

Comment: And if linear programming can be used here why can't we use linear programming for all dp problems?

Comment: In classical problems like knapsack where DP can be applied there is only a binary choice: either take an item or leave it. Thus you have 2^n possibilities for n items. In your case, you can use (linear) fractions of items which is a linear problem. You can create an "area" of valid fractions where one is the optimal solution.

Comment: Also refer to this thread regarding knapsack / linear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600524/why-solving-knapsack-probl-is-not-considered-as-linear-programming

Comment: Thanks! Will have to read up on Linear Programming and try again.

Comment: I have a doubt, here :....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289032/solving-a-linear-program-in-case-of-an-equality-constraint ... Can you please look into It?

Comment: someone already answered there :) you can rewrite your equations to a "standard form"